# How to refresh content in a div not using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html

For example if I use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">` but only on a specific div.

Comment: That is the whole thing with AJAX, you cant otherwise. (if not using an iframe of course). A simple jquery load() does it for you.

Comment: Without AJAX you can't do anything but refresh the entire page.

Comment: the content that must be in the div is dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML
The Asynchronous part refers to additional i/o with your webserver, no longer in sync with actions taken by the surfer (ie reloading the site).
It was designed to do exactly this; update parts of the website without a refresh.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O and 
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

If there's a specific reason why you don't wish to use AJAX (or jquery),
do post the reason; chances are that your objections can easily be overcome.

Remember that even google uses AJAX, which they wouldn't unless it was very widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

If the client side computer already knows or can calculate what the contents of the div should be, you can use jQuery such as:

```
$('#div_id').html('The new contents');
```

If the contents come from the server, you will either have to refresh the whole page or use ajax